# HTML Background Image wont cover entire height

Tags: css

I need the background image in my container div to stretch the entire length of my website.

However, at the moment it gets cut off midway through. The width is perfect and I cannot repeat the image, as the image contains some content.

I tried `background-size:100%",height:100%` as well, but it didn't help.

```
    <body>
<div id="container">
<div id="logo">
</div>
<div id="navigation">

    <ul id="nav">

        <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Recipes</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">The Author</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>

</div>


<div id="spoons">
</div>
<div id="shbox">
<div id="main">
<div id="center">


<div id="gallery">


</div>
</div>
<div style="clear:both"></div>

<div id ="aboutbox" class="shadow" >
<p style="padding: 20px; text-align:center;">Lorem ipsum </p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="footer">
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#">The Author</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div id="clear">
</div>
</div>

</body>
```

CSS

```
#container
{
    margin: 0 auto;


    background-image:url('backg.jpg');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
       position:relative; z-index:1;
        width:990px; 

}
#logo
{
height:150px;
}
#navigation
{
    height:40px;
}
#main{
        padding: 50px;

}
#nav{

            list-style:none;
            margin:0;
            padding:0;
            text-align:center;
            z-index:10;

        }

#gallery
{
    width:860px;
    height:400px;
    background-color:#FFF;
    float:left;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding:10px;

}
#aboutbox
{
    margin-top:30px;
    width:880px;
    background-color:#FFF;' 
    border-radius: 5px;
    clear:both;
}
#clear
{
    clear:both;
}
.shadow
{
    -moz-box-shadow:    3px 3px 5px 6px #ccc;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px 6px #ccc;
     box-shadow:         3px 3px 5px 6px #ccc;
}

        #fronttext
        {

             color:white;
            text-align:center;

        }

        #footer li{
            position:relative;
            display:inline;
            margin:0;
            padding:0;
        }

        #footer a{
            display:inline-block;
            padding:10px;
            color:white;
        }
```

Comment: please show full code with css

Comment: try after set the min-height and min-width

Comment: Here's a nice read: http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

Comment: and if you can, a [jsfiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) would be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `background-size:cover` as below:

```
#your-container-div{ 
    background: url(your_image.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
    background-size: cover;
}
```